# Can you do parallel build in buildbot using multiprocessing module of python

Tags: python, buildbot

Can you use "multiprocessing" module of python with buildbot to do parallel build? I have been trying to integrate this python module with my buildstep. However, the steps do not execute at all. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You may want to use multiple builds (in the buildbot sense) rather than multiple processes within a single build step.

Comment: So I should rather look for buildbot solution using maybe triggerable?

Comment: Yeah, triggerable can work to create parallel builds. Alternately you can have your changes directly start multiple separate builders that each build + test, if your entire build+test chain is entirely parallel (no shared dependencies between builds etc).